# Is it good idea to develop websites on Angular?

Tags: seo, angular.js

I developed a web project which is a web service that helps pupils and abiturients to find the most appropriate university based on their needs, grades, preferences. The tech stack is using AngularJS + PHP

It has unique content, about 7000 pages in search engines but only 5-10 people visit the website daily. I believe the main issue is AngularJS, it was designed to develop one-page web applications rather information web services. Even though I am happy with the performance and functionality of the project and I feed search engines with prerendered pages, AngularJS is still not SEO friendly and search engines lower positions because of users behaviour. For example,  WordPress, Joomla websites are picked by search engines up much better but it lacks of flexibility developing new functionality

Could you please advise what is the best way to make website more SEO friendly? 
Update it to Angular 6? Replaced it with PHP + JavaScript?

Comment: "about 7000 pages in search engines" - are you saying that those 7000 indexed pages don't contain the content you want indexed?

Comment: They are indexed in line with what I expected, create a php prerender for that. 
But I can see that search engine don't like my website :)

Comment: If the content is indexed, then the content is indexed. How would changing the technology help with that? Search engines don't penalise sites simply because of the technology used. If the site is not _ranking_ well then maybe there are other external factors at play?

Comment: Maybe related: [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Comment: The project was done for Russia and Yandex is the main search engine there. 
Based on my 5 years experience, I can see that it is not friendly with my angular website because of bad tracking of user behaviour. It is my humble opinion. Thank you for the link